# FTP access to one site is denied

Tags: ftp

I'm filling up one site via FTP. all works fine. But in several days FTP refused to connect.

FileZilla's printing `Connecting xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx..... Connection time out`
IP of server is pinged well.

I had 4 assumptions:

- **Something with Ubuntu**

I've opened VirtualBox with Win XP, installed filezilla there and had the same problem (connection was by nat)

- **My Ubuntu system somewhere blocks this IP address.**

Last three days I spent in another city and there I could connect this FTP. (with the same shortcut I created early - in Ubuntu bookmarks and in Filezilla)

- **Hosting provider of site blocked me.**

I've call to tech support of the site hosting - they sayd they haven't block anyone

- **My provider at home blocked this site.**

I live in student hostel, and I've tried to connect on my roommate's PC - and it connects fine.

Why can this happen? I can't understand.
Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scanning the server with [nmap](http://nmap.org/), this should tell you which ports are available and which are blocked.

Comment: I accept your question, but there is no decision. I was just blocked - Hosting provider confessed in blocking me only for third time I asked.